# retrieving array values from a checkbox php

Tags: php, arrays, checkbox

I'm having trouble seeing what is wrong here. I am trying to delete from my database based on what checkboxes have been checked. 
The if(!empty($_POST['removeCheckbox'])) says removeCheckbox is empty even though when I echo $currentRow[] it shows values. Thanks in advance.

```
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($paperToReview)){    
    if ($row > 0) {
        $currentRow = array($row['uid'], $row['toReview']);
                echo $currentRow[0];
                echo $currentRow[1];            
        echo '<td width = 200><input type="checkbox" name="removeCheckbox[]" value="'.$currentRow.'"> Remove</td>';
    }
}
//Remove button
echo'<td width = 200><td width = 200><td width = 200><td width = 200><td width = 200><input type=submit name=submit value="Remove Checked Rows"></td>';
```

And then here I see if the remove button has been checked and look through all of the checked boxes.

```
    if (isset($_POST['submit']) && $_POST['submit'] =="Remove Checked Rows"){
        if(!empty($_POST['removeCheckbox'])) {
        //deletes row from database
            foreach($_POST['removeCheckbox'] as $check) {
                    DBSubmit("DELETE FROM paper_review WHERE paper_reviewer_id = '" . $check[0] ."' AND paperid = '" . $check[0] ."'");

                }
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure, the sumbiting condition is met ?

Check if you have right values in $_POST variable, simple write something like this, before your submit condition

```
echo(<pre>); print_r($_POST); echo(</pre>);
```

please send more code (how you create a form, what is in post variable)

T.

Comment: the submit condition is met, I previously had a header(redirect()) under there to see that it was working

Comment: actually the if(!empty($_POST['removeCheckbox'])) check is not working. I'll try to mess around with that

Answer (score 0):

This will make all values as 'Array' because you cannot echo array directly
try this:

```
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($paperToReview)){    
    if ($row > 0) {
        $currentRow = array($row['uid'], $row['toReview']);         
        echo '<td width = 200><input type="checkbox" name="removeCheckbox[]" value="'.json_encode($currentRow).'"> Remove</td>';
    }
}
//Remove button
echo'<td width = 200><td width = 200><td width = 200><td width = 200><td width = 200><input   type=submit name=submit value="Remove Checked Rows"></td>';
```

And in the controller code

```
    if (isset($_POST['submit']) && $_POST['submit'] =="Remove Checked Rows"){
    if(!empty($_POST['removeCheckbox'])) {
    //deletes row from database
        foreach($_POST['removeCheckbox'] as $jsonCheck) {
                $check = json_decode($jsonCheck);
                DBSubmit("DELETE FROM paper_review WHERE paper_reviewer_id = '" . $check[0] ."' AND paperid = '" . $check[0] ."'");

            }
    }
```

You can replace json_encode/decode with serialize/unserialize or any other method

Comment: the if(!empty($_POST['removeCheckbox'])) is not working though. I echoed $currentRow[0] before the checkbox to make sure there were values in the database and they showed up as expected.